# Porting ajaxified pages from IE to firefox/chrome

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest

I need to port an old IE-only ajax webapp to a more modern browser. What are the differences in xmlhttprequest behavior that i should be aware of? Are the DOM differences more important?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer to your question, but the best thing would probably be to port it to a modern *library* like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) that will work in any fairly modern browser, including IE.

It will probably require you to rewrite large parts of the application, but the resulting code is very likely to be much simpler and smaller than the old one. jQuery has shorthand notation and robust functions for most everyday use cases.

For example, see the [jQuery Ajax functions](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)